# RSPEC trying to confirm Class gets called

Tags: rspec, sidekiq

I'm using the concurrency feature in Sidekiq and want to confirm that Sidekiq::Limiter is getting called.  I'm getting the following error:

```rb
Failures:

  1) Op::QueueProcessing#perform concurrency is concurrent per client
     Failure/Error: expect(Sidekiq::Limiter).to have_received(:unlimited)
     
       (Sidekiq::Limiter).unlimited(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/workers/op/queue_processing_spec.rb:24:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/timezone.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/timezone.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Worker Class:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Op
  class QueueProcessing
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def self.throttle
      return Sidekiq::Limiter.unlimited if Rails.env.test?

      Sidekiq::Limiter.concurrent(
        'analytics',
        1,
        wait_timeout: 5,
        lock_timeout: 120
      )
    end

    LIMITER = throttle

    def perform
      uploaded_submissions = OnClaimsSubmission.uploaded_submissions
      uploaded_submissions.each do |submission|
        LIMITER.within_limit do
          Op::ProcessDownloadedFiles.perform_async(*submission)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

describe Op::QueueProcessing do
  describe '#perform' do
    let(:job) { described_class.new }

    context 'concurrency' do
      before do
        allow(Sidekiq::Limiter).to receive(:unlimited)
        job.perform
      end

      it 'is concurrent per client' do
        expect(Sidekiq::Limiter).to have_received(:unlimited)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's because `LIMITER = throttle` is part of the class definition and is executed when the file is loaded, which happens when your spec-helper require's your ruby files.

The method is not called when your test executes, hence the failure.

A relatively simple change would be to change:

```
LIMITER.within_limit do
```

to

```
self.class.throttle.within_limit do
```

However this would have a (likely negligible) performance impact.

Otherwise you'll need to test the value of Op::QueueProcesssing::LIMITER that was assigned at load time. For example, expecting that `Op::QueueProcesssing::LIMITER.is_a?(Sidekiq::Limiter::Unlimited)`